# Send character from arduino to python decode error

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, arduino, decode

I try to send string from arduino to python via bluetooth
but when I try it looks like worked, but received data doesn't looks like what I want

This is my code

[Arduino]

```
void Send_Joystick(int X, int Y)
{

      if(800 <= X && X < 1023 && 700 <= Y && Y < 1025){ BTSerial.write(byte(10);}
  else if(600 <= X && X < 800 && 700 <= Y && Y < 1025){ BTSerial.write(byte(11);}
  else if(400 <= X && X < 600 && 700 <= Y && Y < 1025){ BTSerial.write(byte(12);}
  else if(200 <= X && X < 400 && 700 <= Y && Y < 1025){ BTSerial.write(byte(13);}
  else if(0 <= X && X < 200 && 700 <= Y && Y < 1025){   BTSerial.write(byte(14);}

  else if(800 <= X && X < 1025 && 300 <= Y && Y < 700){ BTSerial.write(byte(15);}
  else if(600 <= X && X < 800 && 300 <= Y && Y < 700){  BTSerial.write(byte(16);}
  else if(400 <= X && X < 600 && 300 <= Y && Y < 700){  BTSerial.write(byte(17);}
  else if(200 <= X && X < 400 && 300 <= Y && Y < 700){  BTSerial.write(byte(18);}        
  else if(0 <= X && X < 200 && 300 <= Y && Y < 700){    BTSerial.write("19>");}

  else if(800 <= X && X < 1025 && 0 <= Y && Y < 300){   BTSerial.write("20>");}
  else if(600 <= X && X < 800 && 0 <= Y && Y < 300){    BTSerial.write("21>");}
  else if(400 <= X && X < 600 && 0 <= Y && Y < 300){    BTSerial.write("22>");}
  else if(200 <= X && X < 400 && 0 <= Y && Y < 300){    BTSerial.write("23>");}
  else if(0 <= X && X < 200 && 0 <= Y && Y < 300){      BTSerial.write("24>");}

}
```

this is just part of my code and looks different with BTSerial
because I tried many ways

[Python3]

```
import bluetooth

bd_addr = "98:D3:37:00:8D:39" # The address from the HC-05 sensor
port = 1
sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((bd_addr,port))


while True:
    try:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        print(data)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
sock.close()



#while True:
#    try:
#        data = sock.recv(1024)
#        print("received [%s]" %data)
#    except KeyboardInterrupt:
#        break
#sock.close()





# below this was in the main code below "data = sock.recv(1024)" phrase
#data_end = data.find('>')
#        if data_end != -1:
#            rec = data[:data_end]
#            print(rec)
#            data = data[data_end+1:]
```

and this was my python code
and when I did this python shell shows me something like this

> b'\xc3\xcc\xcf'
>   b'\xc3'
>   b'\xec\xcf'
>   b'\xc3'
>   b'\xec\xce'
>   b'\xc3\xec\xcf'
>   b'\xc3\xcc'
>   b'\xcf'
>   b'\xc3'
>   b'\xec\xcf'
>   b'\xc3\xec\xcf'
>   b'\xc3\xcc\xcf'

and when I change my python code to

```
data = sock.recv(1024).decode
```

the outcome looks like this

> built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x2d1bd40
>   built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x2d1bd70
>   built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x2d1bda0
>   built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x2d1bdd0
>   built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x2d1be00
>   built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x2d1be30
>   built-in method decode of bytes object at 0x2d1be60

I want to received data as same as i sent from arduino
but every trying always not work

How can I get this work?

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you are supposed to call the `decode` method not return the method itself.

Comment: Looking at your received data as bits I see a lot of duplicated bits. I suspect this is a baudrate problem.

Comment: ah baudrate? ok ill fix it with that